# Work with returning Neo4j nodes in a javascript project

Tags: javascript, neo4j, cypher

in my javascript project i use long cypher queries. The beginning of the queries are quite similar. Can i use the node return of one function in a new querie somehow? I use neo4j-driver and the community neo4j version. To simplify my problem i changed the querie in my example.

```
const doSomething1 = async() =>{
    let query = [
        'MATCH (person:Person)',
        'RETURN person'
    ].join('\n');

    let _person = await session.run(query,{});
    return _person;
};

const doSomething2 = async() =>{
    let _person = await doSomething1();
    let query = [
        'WITH {_testPerson} as _testPerson', 
        'WHERE _testPerson.age = 18',
        'RETURN person'
    ].join('\n');

    let _resultTestPerson = await session.run(query,{
        _testPerson: _person,
    });
    return _resultTestPerson;
};
```

I expect that the "doSomething2" function will return all nodes that are age 18.

Answer (score 1):

Try looking into the [UNWIND](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/unwind/) operator: it takes an array and lets you run a query on each element in it. Your second query might look something like this:

```
UNWIND {arrayOfPeople} AS person
WHERE person.age = 18
RETURN person
```

On a side note, the example you gave could be written as one pretty simple query. Maybe your actual problem could be solved in just one query:

```
MATCH (p:Person)
WHERE p.age = 18
RETURN p
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Im aware that i could write it in one query. I just used a simple example to demonstrate what i wanted to do.

Answer (score 0):

Since `doSomething1` already got all the `Person` nodes, `doSomething2` does not need to make another neo4j query.

Instead, `doSomething2` should just iterate through the `doSomething1` results and filter for the nodes of interest.